# TL-WN725N v2 WiFi adapter not working on Raspberry Pi Arch Linux

Tags: wifi, archlinux, driver, wireless-adapter, realtek

I have a TL-WN725N v2 WiFi adapter and I can't get it working on Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux. Linux kernel version is 3.18.5-1-ARCH #1.

Some time ago, to make this adapter working, it was necessary to compile driver for every kernel version. Now I found that not so long ago the driver was included into kernel. I have tested it on Raspbian and it works. However I can't say the same about Arch Linux.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it, but here's what I tried to look at so far:

- `ifconfig`

  ```
  eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  
      ether b8:27:eb:1b:a5:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
      RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
      TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0  

  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536  
      inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  
      inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>  
      loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)  
      RX packets 960  bytes 75840 (74.0 KiB)    
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
      TX packets 960  bytes 75840 (74.0 KiB)  
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```

No needed `wlan0` interface.

- `ip link`

  ```
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default   
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
  2: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 32  
  link/ether 82:7b:8e:6f:66:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
  3: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 32  
  link/ether 6e:7a:fd:64:91:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
  4: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000  
  link/ether b8:27:eb:1b:a5:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
  5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000  
  link/ether c0:4a:00:12:d1:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```

However `wlan0` is listed here. If I try `ip link set wlan0 up` it says `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready` .

- lsusb

  `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter`
- lsmod

  ```
  Module                  Size  Used by  
  joydev                  9070  0   
  evdev                   9900  0   
  hid_logitech_dj        10218  0   
  r8188eu               430207  0   
  leds_gpio               3492  0   
  led_class               4066  1 leds_gpio  
  uio_pdrv_genirq         3238  0   
  uio                     8753  1 uio_pdrv_genirq    
  sch_fq_codel            7611  2   
  snd_bcm2835            19740  0   
  snd_pcm                86628  1 snd_bcm283  
  snd_timer              20697  1 snd_pcm  
  snd                    61799  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm  
  bcm2708_rng             1044  0   
  rng_core                5666  1 bcm2708_rng  
  ipv6                  327644  14
  ```

Here, I believe, it shows that r8188eu (the driver for the adapter) is there.

Still there's no connectivity and no blinking blue light.

I would highly appreciate any help or directions how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

None of this is necessary anymore.

I have an old model B and had all the problems with the TP-Link 725N and the RTL8188 drivers years ago. I got the same problem when I updated.

However, today I just reflashed my SD Card with Raspbian Stretch and the old WiFi dongle worked out of the box: no config required at all.

Answer (score 0):

For others, who stumbled on this question, try this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192404.

The threads, mentions to use `packer` to install necessary module.

```
packer -Ss dkms-8188eu # search for driver
packer -S dkms-8188eu # install the driver
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also come in handy when using USB Dongles with certain drivers, where making the module available on during boot process can help set up the link for `wlan0`. I tried this, however on **Raspbian Jessie** with a **LogiLink WL0145N** WLAN which also has the `r8188eu` driver on it.

Inside the `/etc/modules` file add `r8188eu` (also add `ipv6` if needed in the same file) and then reboot. This might do make the module available for the WLAN dongle and making the link ready for usage.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using this Wi-Fi adapter. I have some problems with this Wi-Fi adapter on my Raspbian Wheezy. After installing the TP-Link drivers on my Raspbian wheezy it become working. But on Raspbian Jessie we do not want to install TP-Link drivers. However we can use following commands to install driver software:

```
$ curl -s https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/install-8188eu.tgz | tar xz
$ ./install-8188eu.sh -l
$ uname -a
$ ./install-8188eu.sh -k #xxx
```

Then reboot the Pi and check your TP-Link Wi-Fi adaptor's indication LED is blinking or not.

Reference: [thepizzy.net](https://thepizzy.net/blog/2014/05/how-to-install-tp-link-wireless-usb-adapter-on-raspberry-pi/)

But I found that the curl command for that Dropbox content not working nowadays. Since they removes that from Dropbox. But I saved this file on my Google drive. I don't know is it working however I am sharing [TP-link driver software](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HkM_BeqkJxalNTSXVhb1Z0aXM/view?usp=drivesdk).